# Finding the sum of a nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sum

I tried finding the sum of all numbers of a nested array, but I don't get it to work correctly. This is what I tried:

```
function arraySum(i) {
  sum = 0;
  for (a = 0; a < i.length; a++) {
    if (typeof i[a] == 'number') {
      sum += i[a];
    } else if (i[a] instanceof Array) {
      sum += arraySum(i[a]);
    }
  }
  return sum;
}
```

When you try it out with the array `[[1,2,3],4,5]`, it gets `6` as the answer, instead of `15`.
Does somebody know where there is a mistake in it?

Comment: Try moving the `var sum` above the function

Comment: I think declaring:
    var sum = 0;
will do the trick for you. Missing the keyword var.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem with your code is that the `sum` and `a` variables are global, instead of local. Because of this you get an infinite loop (a from the first entry in the function is reset by the second entry, so the same elements are processed again).

Fix it by adding `var` to where `sum` and `a` are declared to make them local to the function:

```
function arraySum(i) {
    var sum=0; // missing var added
    for(var a=0;a<i.length;a++){ // missing var added
        if(typeof i[a]=="number"){
            sum+=i[a];
        }else if(i[a] instanceof Array){
            sum+=arraySum(i[a]);
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/eGaFOLA/2/edit

Comment: +1, it seems everyone spotted the missing `var` for sum, but nobody noticed it missing in the for loop. Well done on the spot, and explaining the problem too!

Answer (score 5):

I know it's late, but they say "is never late" :)

```
const sumNestedArray = arr => arr.flat(Infinity).reduce((a,b)=> a+b, 0)
```

```js
const sumNestedArray = arr => arr.flat(Infinity).reduce((a,b)=> a+b, 0)

console.log(sumNestedArray([1,[2], [2, 3, [4]]]))
```

```
sumNestedArray([1,[2], [2, 3, [4]]])
```

Answer (score 3):

For 2018 this solution is clean and functional:

```
let arr = [[ 1, 2, 3], 4, 5]
arr.flat().reduce((d, i) => d + i)
```

Documentation for [flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/flat) and [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

(My assumption is that you want to parse strings, e.g., '13', into numbers in order include them in the sum. If not, just change `isNumber` to `typeof val === 'number'`.

```
function arraySum(arr) {
  let sum = 0;

  while (arr.length) {
    const val = arr.pop();
    const isArray = typeof val === 'object' && val.length !== undefined;
    const isNumber = !isArray && !isNaN(sum + parseFloat(val)); 

    if (isArray && val.length) {
      sum += arraySum(val);
    }
    else if (isNumber) {
      sum += parseFloat(val);
    }
  }

  return sum;
}

console.log(arraySum([])); //0
console.log(arraySum([1, 1, 1, [3, 4, [8]], [4]])); //22
console.log(arraySum([1, 1, [], {}, 'l', 1, [3, 4, [8]], [4]])); //22
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing two `var` in there. You've implicitly declared `sum` and `a` at window scope:

```
function arraySum(i) {
    **var** sum=0;
    for(**var** a=0;a<i.length;a++){
        if(typeof i[a]=="number"){
            sum+=i[a];
        }else if(i[a] instanceof Array){
            sum+=arraySum(i[a]);
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: I thought this too, but testing it still results in 6

Comment: Var doesnt do that :)

Answer (score 0):

Recurse, for example

```
function arraySum(x) {
    var sum = 0, i;
    if (typeof x === 'number')
        return x;
    else if (x instanceof Array)
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; ++i)
            sum += arraySum(x[i]);
    return sum;
}
arraySum([[1,2,3],4,5]); // 15
```

I didn't optimise this so that it's clear, you may want some more logic before recursion.

---

The reason yours isn't working is because you need to `var` both `sum` and `a`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all why you use 'i' as input to function? we using 'i' to denote running index..
Regarding your question,you want 'a' to be local in your loop so instead of "for(a=0;..." instead write "for(var a=0;"

```
    <html>
    <body>
        <script>
            function NestedArraySummation(arr)
            {
                var sum=0;
                for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
                {
                    if(typeof arr[i]=="number")
                    sum=sum+arr[i];
                    else  if(arr[i] instanceof Array)
                        sum=sum+NestedArraySummation(arr[i]);
                }
                    return sum;
            }

            var MyArray=[1,[2,3],4,10,[1,2]];
            var Sum=NestedArraySummation(MyArray);
            document.write(Sum);

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with lodash [`_.flattenDeep`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#flattenDeep) and [`_.sum`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#sum):

```js
const arr = [[1, 2, 3], 4, 5];
arraySum(arr);

function arraySum(arr) {
  var arrFlattens = _.flattenDeep(arr);
  // => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
  console.log(_.sum(arrFlattens));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This was posted long ago but it might help others. I did the following and it seems to be working just fine

```js
function countArray (array) {
 //iterate through the array
for(let i = 0;i < array.length; i++){
//check if element of array is an array, and if it is, run method flat() to the whole array. 
  if(Array.isArray(array[i])){
    array = array.flat()
  }
}
//return the sum of the elements of the array
 return array.reduce((a,b) => a + b);
    
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
from __builtin__ import int
def nestedLists(mylist):
    sum = 0
    if checkIfAllInt(mylist):
        result = addList(mylist)
        return result
    else:
        for value in mylist:
            sum = sum + nestedLists(value)
    return sum        

def addList(listdata):
    if(type(listdata) is int):
        return listdata
    else:
        return sum(listdata)    

def checkIfAllInt(listdata):
    check = True
    if(type(listdata) is int):
        return check
    else:
        for value in listdata:
            if(not type(value) is int):
                check = False
                return check
    return check    

print nestedLists([1,[2,3,[4,5,[6,7]]]])
```

Comment: Properly formatted code is always easy to read and understand. I've formatted this answer for you. Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) help guide on formatting.

Comment: Please explain how this code solves the OP's problem.

Comment: You answered in the wrong programming language ... Also "`from __builtin__ import int`" o_O