# how are elements in a nested array added?

Tags: javascript

```js
let array = [[1,4], [11], [3,5,7]];

console.log(0+array[0]+array[1]+array[2]);
console.log(array.reduce((acc, value)=>acc+value, 0));
```

This prints the following on the console :

```
01,4113,5,7  
01,4113,5,7
```

I was trying to add all elements of the array and stumbled upon the above code. I know the spread operator and how I can add all the elements. I know what's happening here is concatenation and not addition. I am just not able to understand this output. Can someone tell me what is happening here?

Comment: You can see output, its just concatenating, [Read More](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascriptss-addition-operator-demystified/)

Comment: `[1,4] + [11]` will not sum the two objects. It would convert them to strings.

Comment: And if an array is converted to a string, comma's are used as a seperator

Comment: So 0 + [1,4] is 01,
and 0 + [1,4] +[ 11] is 01, 411 
Why ?

Comment: No 0 + [1,4] is 01,4. Adding the array [11] will result in 01,411

Comment: @Wimanicesir - thank you. Got it. It's taking the first element and concatenating.
0 + array[0] gives 01,4
0+array[0]+array[1] gives 01,411
0+array[0]+array[1]+array[2] gives 01,4113,5,7

Answer (score 0):

```js
let array = [[1,4], [11], [3,5,7]];
console.log(array.reduce((acc, value)=>acc+value, 0));
```

Here, each `acc` is an array, so (as stated in the comments) the array will be converted to a string (`+`) and js will implode it with comma's.

To get the sum of all the nested arrays, you'll need calculate the sum of the deeper array before adding:

Example using the new [`flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat);

```js
let array = [[1,4], [11], [3,5,7]];
let sum = array.flat().reduce((acc,value)=> acc + value)
console.log(sum);
```

Example using a nested `reduce`:

```js
let array = [[1,4], [11], [3,5,7]];
console.log(array.reduce((acc, value)=> acc + value.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0), 0));
// 1+4+11+3+5+7
// 31
```

---

There are many other options to get the desired results, using the new `flat()` or an recursive function can be found here;

- [Finding the sum of a nested array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19181515/finding-the-sum-of-a-nested-array)
- [Sum nested array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50768119/sum-nested-array)
- [How to sum nested arrays in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65362738/how-to-sum-nested-arrays-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Loop through each sub-array on an outer loop and add each number of each sub-array in an inner loop.

```js
let twoDArray = [
  [1, 4],
  [11],
  [3, 5, 7]
];

const sumOfArrays = array => {
  let sum = 0;
  for (let arr of array) {
    for (let num of arr) {
      sum += num;
    }
  }
  return sum;
}

console.log(sumOfArrays(twoDArray));
```

Answer (score -1):

To make a long story short, "reduce()" basically performs a loop.  Instead of using an actual handwritten loop within your code, the work is done by programming within the JavaScript interpreter itself, in a single efficient operation.

[Here is an older StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49934992/main-difference-between-map-and-reduce) which includes some nice graphics to explain the processes of "map" and "reduce."